# i'm trying to make a reference to the admin that registered the customer in my customer schema but it's returning an empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, populate

```
AdminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username : {type : String, required : true, unique: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    date : {type: Date, default: Date.now}
 })


customerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname :{type: String, required: true},
    lastname : {type: String, required: true},
    email : {type: String, required: true, unique : true},
    account_type : {type: String, required : true},
    account_number : {type: Number, default : Math.floor(Math.random() * 
    (9999999999))},
    account_balance : {type : Number, required : true},
    password : {type : String, required : true},
    admin_id : [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'admin'}] //look here
});

 //trying to insert a customer here..   
exports.RegisterCustomer = (req, res, next) => {
    var customer = req.body,

        customerObj = new cusModel(customer);

        customerObj.save((err, data) => {
            if(err){ return next( new Error("can't register customer"));}
            res.status(200).json(data);
        })
 } //the insert function for customer...
```

what's the next step cos the admin_id is returning an empty array upon trying to post a customer.

what am i doing wrong or probably missing?

Comment: Hi, can you include also the inserting function/queries?

Comment: it's been included, please check it out.